# Why is my effects composer outputting odd lines in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, frontend

I am currently attempting to add FXAA post-processing onto my site but when the site is rendered on any computer it displays something like this:
[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS9JM.png)

I've tried to replace code and mess with it but the code either doesn't work or outputs the exact same image. The standard image when using the default renderer outputs this: [image of render without composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBVjw.jpg)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what would my next steps be in order to render this out correctly?

Here is the code I have setup for my effects composer:

```
  //Effects Composer
  var composer = new EffectComposer(renderer);

  //

  var renderPass = new RenderPass(scene, camera);
  var fxaaPass = new ShaderPass(FXAAShader);
  var copyPass = new ShaderPass(CopyShader);


  // Adding Effects Composer

  const pixelRatio2 = renderer.getPixelRatio();

  fxaaPass.material.uniforms['resolution'].value.x = 1 / (container.offsetWidth * pixelRatio2);
  fxaaPass.material.uniforms['resolution'].value.y = 1 / (container.offsetHeight * pixelRatio2);

  
  composer.addPass(renderPass);
  composer.addPass(fxaaPass);
  composer.addPass(copyPass);
```

Here is also my animation loop as well:

```
//Animation Loop
  function animate() {

    if (RESOURCES_LOADED == false) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      loadingScreen.box.position.x -= 0.01;
      if (loadingScreen.box.position.x < -10) {
        loadingScreen.box.position.x = 10;
      }
      loadingScreen.box.position.y = Math.sin(loadingScreen.box.position.x);
      renderer.render(loadingScreen.scene, loadingScreen.camera);
      return;

    }

    //cloud/flash animation
    cloudparticles.forEach(p => {
      p.rotation.z -= 0.002;
    });

    if (Math.random() > 0.93 || flash.power > 100) {
      if (flash.power < 100)
        flash.position.set(
          Math.random() * 400,
          300 + Math.random() * 200,
          100
        );
      flash.power = 50 + Math.random() * 500;
    }



    //object spin
    if (dazeMesh) {
      let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
      dazeMesh.position.y = Math.sin(dazeMesh.userData.initFloating + t) * .1;
      dazeMesh.rotation.y += 0.005;
    }

    //camera animation

    target.x = (1 - mouse.x) * 0.0002;
    target.y = (1 - mouse.y) * 0.0002;

    camera.rotation.x += 0.05 * (target.y - camera.rotation.x);
    camera.rotation.y += 0.05 * (target.x - camera.rotation.y);

    //render confirmation
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    renderer.clear();

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    renderer.render(lightingScene, camera);

  }
```